# Elastic beanstalk 502 bad gateway nginx error only on https

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, nginx, https, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am trying to set up https to be used over my node.js elastic beanstalk server. I configured the listeners with the certificate I want to use, and created the corresponding A record name in route 53 but it still wont work over https. However, when I use http and not https it seems to work fine for the default / route that just returns "healthy" as the response. I am not sure exactly what logs to look for, but let me know and I can post them. This is the error I get over https:

[image]